# Installation Query Access Database Engine 2010

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to install the Access Database Engine 2010 on some PC's in our office.

On some PC's - not all, i receive the message that the installation cannot proceed due to some 64bit Office Products being installed (image attached below).

I have checked all Office versions on the PC by going into Help - About and all are 32bit. The 32bit package was downloaded from our Microsoft365 subscription portal.

We need to install the 32bit version as the 64bit wont work with our other application.

Is there a way where i can somehow find which component is 64bit? I have tried to find the differences between the PC's and am not having much luck.

thanks,[image: 32bit ACE error]

Comment: Eh... The error message already says which component is 64-bit: Microsoft Access database engine 2010 (English). Apparently, you installed the 64-bit version first and haven't removed it (or haven't removed it properly at least, this tends to happen when not rebooting after removing something, and then installing/removing something else which conflicts)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because error message is explicit and resolution is obvious.

Comment: According to the Add / Remove Programs from the control panel there is no other Database Engines installed. This is why i'm here, it doesn't make sense to me. I'm not asking this question to waste anyone's time, im asking because i have tried to troubleshoot myself and haven't got any closer. I'm hoping there might be some trick to find it easily. I have tried installing the 32bit Engine on a PC that hasn't (to my knowledge) had this installed previously, yet the above error occurs, but not always.